# How to train my griffin?

Tags: the-last-guardian

I recently adopted this adorable griffin. After nursing it back to health (it was a stray!) I thought I'd try training it. To my surprise, it doesn't seem to want to listen to a word I say!

I love my Trico just the way it is, but I'd love it even more if it would listen to me. Any tips for a new pet owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, disobedience is a common problem among griffins. However, I was able to find a useful guide [here](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/last-guardian-trico-training-guide-make-trico-follow-your-commands-572458):

> You’ll earn the trust of Trico faster by **petting it**, **pulling out any spears or arrows** and **feeding it barrels**.

From the pet care guide above, it seems that you can pet *and* remove arrows and spears from your Trico by approaching it and holding the Circle button. (I think Trico likes being pet on its head more than anywhere else!)

As for your Trico's diet, it only eats **glowing barrels** so make sure to give it as many as you can find. Make sure your Trico is eating them, though, sometimes it will simply ignore them!

> If Trico isn’t responding to you, there could also be a few obstacles distracting it.

Your Trico will also get distracted by green smoke and stained glass eyes. You'll need to either destroy or hide the eyes or destroy the source of the green smoke. Sometimes suits of armor will hold up shields with the eye on them as well. You can make them drop the shields by dashing into them with the Square button.

However, it's important to note that even after doing these things, **Trico may still disobey you**. It *is* an animal after all!